# How to make a button light up on hover with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site using the twitter bootstrap CSS, but I've run into a problem.

[nav bar example](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

If you look towards the end, "Bootstrap" is sort of hidden; it only lights up when you mouseover it (but it is, by default, black). How do I get this functionality for a button in my webpage?

Here's my navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
           <a href="./home.html" class="brand" color="black"></a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="./tutoring.html">Tutoring</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="./competitions.html">Competitions</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="./board.html">Board Members</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="./info.html">Info</a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <span class="span5"></span>
              </li>
              <li class="" id="algebrayall">
                <a class="brand pull-right" style="color:black" href="./index.html">It's just algebra, y'all</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I want the `<a class="brand pull-right" style="color:black" href="./index.html">It's just algebra, y'all</a>` part to work like their Bootstrap button.

Comment: There is no such attribute `color="black"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not part of Bootstrap.css. It is part of the twitter documentation website css (docs.css).

This is the base `brand` styling:

```
body > .navbar .brand {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 0 30px rgba(255,255,255,.125);
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

And the hover effect:

```
body > .navbar .brand:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1), 0 0 30px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

.navbar-inverse .brand:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .brand:focus, .navbar-inverse .nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

There might be some more styling that makes up the full effect, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are overriding the text color of brand using inline style which overrides the bootstrap styles

Instead of using inline styling for changing the color of brand, use a class

```
.navbar-inverse.navbar .brand {
    color: black;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eUv5M/)

**Important**
But I think the correct solution will be to create a [custom version of bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html) by changing the `@navbarBrandColor` property to what ever you want instead of manually overriding the style in your css file

Comment: This is about the same as what SimonC posted above (and I think it would accomplish the same except pull-right -- and I think I could just add class="pull-right" to fix that). Thanks!